# Calculating percent change in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

Using standard Excel 2010 I am trying to calculate percent change from 2013 to 2014 and put that in a column after grand total.

The formula I am trying to use is `(2013 - 2014) / 2013`

I have tried *Calculated Field* but that hasn't worked, and I can't do *Calculated Item* since I grouped my dates to show in years instead of days.

[image]

This is what the source data looks like :

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, that is. I want to see the negative numbers. Do you have a different formula in mind?

Comment: This looks helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGRX843rzcI

Comment: @pnuts no worries. We are all guilty of that ;)

Comment: @user2348184 yeah, but wasn't for percent change, just for percent

Comment: @pnuts updated question with source data

Comment: @pnuts oh no... I didn't include the customer names in what I am showing you. That is how the rows are laid out.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you now have `Sales` in the value field and `Year` in the column field

Add `Sales` to the value field again

Click the drop down for your second `Sales`

Go to "Value Field Settings"

Go to show "Show Value As" in the tab

"Show Values As" scroll to "% Difference From"

Base Field is `Year`

Base item is `Previous`

Comment: To add to @pnuts it works, but now I have 2 empty columns, which I can hide, but I would like to get rid of them permanently.